# Java Static Method Calling

Tags: java, object, static-methods

is Calling a static Java method ( a factory class method ) creates an object of that Class ?

I mean a static method returns a value let's say an Array's size ( array is variable of class )

I've checked the code but couldn't see that the Object of that class never instantiated before calling the static method. ?

```
public static boolean isFiveInstance() {
    return _instances.size() == 5;
}
```

and _instances is class variable

```
private static ArrayList<LocalMediaPlayer> _instances;
```

and is being created and filled in the constructer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `static` invocations do not instantiated objects (because they do not require one).

The first time you refer to a class, including static method invocation, the class is loaded. by the classloader.

That's where the static initializer comes into play:

```
static {
     // do something
}
```

this block is called whenever the class is initialized (once per classloader)

Comment: so ? when I call a static method of the class by 
    Class.staticMEthod();
this static block is also invoketed, right ?
where this static block is in the constructer.

Comment: the staic block is invoked the first time you refer to the class. And it is placed outside the constructor

Comment: ok, I think I got the point. first, you are right it is out of the constructor ( my mistake ). And since I am **referring** the class by calling the static method like `Class.StaticMethod();` it is executing the static block as well. Even if I dont have a Class instance created.

Comment: Here is a link for those who want to check more in details.
[External Page](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php)

Answer (score 4):

No it does not. That is the point behind creating static methods. Static methods use no instance variables of any object of the class they are defined in either, so everything you refer to inside your static method must be static also.

That is why you call a static method like `Class.StaticMethod()` instead of:

```
new Class().StaticMethod();
```

the `new` will instantiate that class, thus creating a new instance of that object.

Answer (score 2):

No, calling a static method does not create an instance of the class. That's where static methods differ from instance methods. They don't need an instance of the class they belong to to be instantiated to be run.